# How to integrate font-awesome 5.3 in grails 2.4.4 version without cdn link

Tags: grails, font-awesome

I'm trying to integrate font-awesome 5.3 in grails 2.4.4 version, and I'm not supposed to use cdn link. 
Since grails 2.4.4 doesn't have dependency plugin support for font-awesome 5.3, I can not use the dependency plugins as well.

I just downloaded the bundle and tried to copy all files into my project folder and imported the all.css file into my main.gsp file, but that didn't work. 
Is there any other approach to fix this? [OR] Did I do anything wrong while placing the bundle files into my project?
Can someone suggest me the best approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails 2.4.4 already includes [asset-pipeline plugin](http://asset-pipeline.com/). So the process that I have adopted is the following:

1. Create a directory that I usually call vendor in `/grails-app/assets` directory, here all css client dependencies should be located, as in your case `font-awesome`.
2. In `/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file include `font-awesome` as a dependency.

Once this is done you will have access to the icons from the views that depend on `application.css` file.

I attach an example

Directory tree

[image]

`/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```
/*
*= require main
*= require mobile
*= require fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css
*= require_self
*/
```

In order to test, in this example I add an icon in the `h1` tag in view `/grails-app/views/index.gsp` that extends from /grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp and that in turn extends from `application.css`

So in `/grails-app/views/index.gsp` I add the icon

```
<h1>Application Status <i class="fab fa-font-awesome"></i></h1>
```

Result

[image]